# How can i use bootstrap confirm or alert function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap alert and confirm function in `js` file. But I don't know how can I use it?

```
function () {

        Bootstrap.alert("d");
}
```

When I do this, Console error say

> BootStrap is not defined

So how I can use bootstrap functionality in `js` file.?

Comment: check this :http://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/#

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts) is complete usage of bootstrap alert. The correct syntax is to use alert function on your element by using jquery selector, not on Bootstrap.

`$('.alertbox').alert();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: We used javascript like this
alert("");
Can we use bootstrap alert without any selector?

Comment: No, bootstrap's alert function can only be triggered on element. So we have to specify the selector.